# Not making list of urls in scrapy spider

Tags: python, url, scrapy, web-crawler

I have created a scrapy spider that has to crawl the whole webpage and extract the urls. now I have to remove the social media URL for that I want to make a list of the URLs, but somehow it's not working. when I try to append each URL in list it just continuously make list of urls.

```
import re
import scrapy
all_urls = []
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'

    start_urls = [
            'https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/i/ip.html',
        ]
    def parse(self, response):
        page= response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename='quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        for r in response.css('a'):
            url = r.css('::attr(href)').get()
            print('all the urls are here', url)
            for i in url:
                all_urls.append(url)
                print(all_urls)
```

Edit:

I have removed the social media links and other info from the list now I want to scrape each link further kindly see if my approach is fine.

```
import requests
import scrapy
all_urls = []
remove = ["twitter"]
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotess'
    start_urls = [
            'https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/i/ip.html',
         ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('a::attr(href)').getall():
            if url.startswith("http"):
                if 'twitter' not in url:
                    all_urls.append(url)
        print(all_urls)
        print(all_urls[0])
        for i in all_urls:
            response = requests.get(i)
            # print(response)
            yield response
```

Comment: You need to yield a request not a response.  Like this `yield scrapy.Request(i)`  and you do not ever need to import requests.  Use the scrapy.Request instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to grab all of the urls on a page would be to chain your css selector and call `getall()`.

For example:

```
import scrapy
all_urls = []

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'

    start_urls = [
            'https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/i/ip.html',
        ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('a::attr(href)').getall():
            all_urls.append(url)
        print(all_urls)
```

OUTPUT

```
['/', '/news/', '#', '/index.html#aboutWS', '/index.html#download', 'https://blog.wireshark.org/', '/code-of-conduct.html', '#', 'https://ask.wireshark.org/', '/faq.html', '/docs/', '/lists/', '/tools/', 'https://gitlab.co
m/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis', 'https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues', '#', '/develop.html', 'https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/', 'https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/tree/master', 'https:/
/www.wireshark.org/download/automated', '../', 'https://twitter.com/wiresharknews', 'https://sysdig.com/privacy-policy/', '#', '#']
```

Comment: I have removed the social media links and other info from the list now I want to scrape each link further, kindly see edit part in post if my approach is fine.

Comment: You need to yield a request not a response. Like this `yield scrapy.Request(i)` and you do not ever need to import `requests`. Use the `scrapy.Request` instead  @samannaz

Comment: if i scrape a list of URLs like this, it just scrapes hundreds of further links by going to every link. what if i do it in a systematic way lets say i have page A , where i found 2 links A1 and A2, now i want to scrape it further as A1.1 .. A1.n , and A2.1 ... A2.n parallelly, for now, it scrape the 1st link and then 2nd .. @Alexander

Comment: Its only doing that because that is what you are telling it to do.  every time you yield a request by default if feeds that request into the parse method. So right now your parse method is grabbing all of the links on a page, filtering some of them out, and then moving on to the next request which will obviously create a never ending sequence.  What you need to do is write a new parse method that will do something different @samannaz

Comment: So for example you start with `link1`  it gets feed to the `parse` method which extracts a bunch of links.... this is where you are now.  you need to decide what you want to do with those links and/or the result of making a request to that link.  once you know that make a new `parse_2` method that does that.